# javascript : How to filter text without spell checking?

Tags: javascript

The goal is to filter some "test" or "flood" messages in a shout box chat.
ex: when an user writes something like

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa or jdhshjdskhdshuishifhduif or dsqjlkdsqjiodsqjiosqjdsjq
```

I want to filter such stupid words: I guess I need to write some functions like:
if string length>20 or string conatins more that 4 vowels in a row or contains 4 consonants in a row

or contains some special chars...

Maybe this function has aleardy been written to avoid reinventing the wheel.

regards

Comment: This sounds fun but the use case seems very rare. Spammers usually try to produce something more alike "normal" text. Do you want to filter out 10 months babies and cats ?

Comment: you are right : more against flooders and testers

Comment: @user300675 to protect against flooding, you don't need to check the contents of the messages, but rather te frequency with which an IP address submits messages. That is simple to set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well using some Regular Expressions could do the trick.

**EDIT**
I have updated the code after [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638344/chris)'s suggestion.
So the credit goes to him.

```
String.prototype.testVowels = function () {
    return !(/([aeiou]){4,}\w*/g.test(this));
}
String.prototype.testConsonants = function () {
    return !(/([bcdfghjklmnpqrstwxyz]){4,}\w*/g.test(this));
}
String.prototype.testLength = function() {
   return this.length < 20;
}

function testString(str) {
   var stringArr = str.split(" ");
   // this will test for each word in the str parameter
   stringArr.forEach(function(s) {
      if(s.testConsonants() && s.testLength() && s.testVowels()) {
         console.log("The word " + s + " is ok !");
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: You can boil down the regexes a lot. For the vowels i suggest: `/([aeiou]){4,}\w*/g` this tests for "4 vowels OR MORE in a row". You can do the same for the consonants.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the head's up, I updated the answer, hope you don't mind

Comment: Your welcome. Of course not. Submitting a seperate answer just to shorten the regexes would be overkill.

Comment: @Chris is smart stackoverflow user :)